# Python polars has a modulus operator but it throws an attribute error

Tags: python, modulo, python-polars

Please see this documentation:
[Docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mod.html)

When I run this code:

```
print(
pl.scan_csv(openpath)
.select(([pl.col('Barcodes'),pl.col('DateTime')]))
.sort('DateTime')
.with_row_count("index").collect().with_column(pl.col('index').mod(2).alias('oddeven')))
```

Throws this error:

> .with_row_count("index").collect().with_column(pl.col('index').mod(2).alias('oddeven')))
> AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'mod'. Did you mean:
> 'mode'?

This might should be a github issue. If so, I will move it there.

Edit: this is due to the older version of polars running on my machine.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the latest version of polars (0.17.2)?

Comment: `mod` was only added 3 weeks ago ([source](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/c88f446b09d2466c8a18c1093f1416e82d5f938e#diff-d42624f72e4b9fc92887180f874e8a4bb1b94fa4e8688830823e3ddad91ff1f9R335)), so you likely just need to make sure you are on the latest version.